# Export groups of Excel columns as CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am attempting to create a series of csv files from my worksheet that contain two columns, one is an "Answer" column and the other is the student response column (denoted by their student number).  The Answer column will be in all exported files and the other will be the specific student response.  I would like the name of the file to be the student number (row 1).  I have tried to alter a few solutions like this one:

```
for i = 1 to 191   
    open "file" & i & ".csv" as #1
    for each c in columns(i).cells
       print #1, c.value
    next c
    close #1
next i
```

But as I am very new to this I cant get it to work.  The structure of my sheet is:

Answers   #######   ####### ...
 A           A         B
.
.
.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will probably want to include the full path in your filename - and you are missing the `For Output` part - `Open sFilename For Output as #1`

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I changed the script to add your changes
For i = 2 To 191
    Open "/Users/username/001.csv" & i & ".csv" For Output As #1
    For Each c In Columns(1 & i).Cells
       Print #1, c.Value
    Next c
    Close #1
Next i

but I must be doing something wrong because it still wont' run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your approach a little bit to make it work.

```
Public Sub CreateCSVs()
Const csOutFolder As String = "C:\Temp" '\\ Change this to suit
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim intFF As Integer
For i = 2 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    intFF = FreeFile
    strFile = csOutFolder & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(1, i).Value & ".csv"
    Open strFile For Output As #intFF
        For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            Print #intFF, Cells(j, 1).Value & "," & Cells(j, i).Value
        Next j
    Close #intFF
Next
End Sub
```